# Generate volume curve from mp3

Tags: python, waveform

I'm trying to build something in python that can analyze an uploaded mp3 and generate the necessary data to build a waveform graphic. Everything I've found is much more complex than I need. Ultimately, I'm trying to build something like you'd see on SoundCloud.

I've been looking into `numpy` and `fft's`, but it all seem more complicated than I need. What's the best approach to this? I'll build the actual graphic using canvas, so don't worry about that part of it, I just need the data to plot.

Comment: `fft` is for the spectrum.  for plotting the volume, you can literally use the waveform itself (or it's square, to be more technically accurate).

Comment: That kind of confirms my suspicion. Can you elaborate a bit more on the particulars (preferred modules, "it's square", or anything else useful)?

Comment: You would need to decode the mp3 file into PCM waveform, which you can store in a `numpy` array.

Answer (score 1):

An MP3 file is an encoded version of a waveform. Before you can work with the waveform, you must first decode the MP3 data into a PCM waveform. Once you have PCM data, each sample represents the waveform's amplitude at the point in time. If we assume an MP3 decoder outputs signed, 16-bit values, your amplitudes will range from -16384 to +16383. If you normalize the samples by dividing each by 16384, the waveform samples will then range between +/- 1.0.

The issue really is one of MP3 decoding to PCM. As far as I know, there is no native python decoder. You can, however, use LAME, called from python as a subprocess or, with a bit more work, interface the LAME library directly to Python with something like SWIG. Not a trivial task.

Plotting this data then becomes an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using Pygame if you don't want to deal with the inner workings of the mp3 file format.

Pygame is a multimedia library which can open common audio file formats - including .mp3 and .ogg as "Sound" objects - if you have Numpy instaled underneath, you can browse the uncompressed (and therefore, post fft transforms) sound, using the pygame.sndarray.array call - which returns a numpy array object with the sound samples.

I've found a little trick - be shure to call pygame.mixer.init with the same parameters (for frequency, bit sample size and n.of channels) as your .mp3 file has, or the call to sndarray.array may raise an Exception.

Check the documentation at http://www.pygame.org/docs/